# Output Get Variables with multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, html, url, url-encoding

I am perplexed in getting the GET Variables for the url of this specific page.

The URL is :-

```
http://thisthat.com/category/?field_issue_month_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=2013&field_issue_month_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D=10
```

I am trying to output both of these GET variables.

I tried following ways and it failed :(

```
echo urldecode("field_issue_month_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D");
     [field_issue_month_value]
echo $_GET['field_issue_month_value[value][year][0]'];
echo $_GET["field_issue_month_value[value][month]"];

echo urldecode($_GET['field_issue_month_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D']);
```

The Var_dump is as follows:-

```
{ ["field_issue_month_value"]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> array(2) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2013" ["month"]=> string(2) "10" } } ["q"]=> string(19) "Page-Name" }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to guess when `print_r($_GET)` will show you exactly what's going on?

Comment: I need to put a condition on what `field_issue_month_value[value][month]` shows, hence I need that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$_GET` contains an array, you should access the data the following way:

Your array is multidimensional, thus you need several indeces to get that data:

```
$_GET['field_issue_month_value']['value']['year'] ;
```

---

Otherwise using `$_GET['field_issue_month_value[value][year][0]'];` you just go 1-level deep, using one string as an index.

---

**UPD:**
This example works fine for me:

```
parse_str(urldecode('field_issue_month_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=2013&field_issue_month_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D=10'), $r);

echo $r['field_issue_month_value']['value']['month'] . "<br/>" ;
echo $r['field_issue_month_value']['value']['year'] . "<br/>" ;
```

Comment: Thanks Jari. But it just shows the first number. For example if the year of the GET variable is 2013, it just shows `2`. Any idea?

Comment: Just a sec, I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Try `$_GET['field_issue_month_value']['value']['year'] ;`in case it does not work, could show us output of `var_dump($_GET)` ?